# how does this batch FOR command translate to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, shutil

I have been trying to figure out how to translate this simple batch code (that deletes every empty dir in a tree) into python and it is taking me an unreasonable amount of time. I kindly ask for a solution with detailed explanation, I believe it will jumpstart my understanding of the language. I'm in danger of giving up.

```
for /d /r %%u in (*) do rmdir "%%u"
```

I do have my grotesque version I am trying to fix which must be all sorts of wrong. I would prefer using the `shutil` module, if suitable.

```
for dirpath in os.walk("D:\\SOURCE")
    os.rmdir(dirpath)
```

Comment: What language is that batch command written in?

Comment: You may be looking for ``os.walk``. It recursively gives you directories and their contents.

Comment: @JohnGordon I thought batch was the name of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to delete the empty directories, then [pathlib.Path(..).glob(..)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) would work:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
emptydirs = [d for d in Path('.').glob('**/*')          # go through everything under '.'
             if d.is_dir() and not os.listdir(str(d))]  # include only directories without contents
for empty in emptydirs:    # iterate over all found empty directories
    os.rmdir(empty)        # .. and remove
```

if you want to delete everything under the directory, then the `shutil.rmtree(..)` function can do it in one line:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('.')
```

check the docs for all the details (https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

Comment: Works great, thanks! Although I'm shocked that it has to be longer than the `batch` version. Meaning the one for empties only.